# <p:selectOneMenu>, filter and converter

Tags: primefaces

I have a menu with filter on. The value and label are both String. In this case, does the "converter" property have to be set? The reason I'm asking is that the filter function is not working if the "converter" is not provided. E.g.,

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{menuBean.selectedCountry}" filter="true" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="US" itemValue="1"/>
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Spain" itemValue="2"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Thank you for your points and help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your primefaces version but this is a bug in 3.4. You can set the height attribute of p:selectOneMenu or you can apply the following fix from here.     [SelectOneMenu with filter not working with less than 10 elements](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4594).

Comment: Thanks for the points. I'm using PrimeFaces 3.3. I added "height" attribute to the <p:selectOneMenu> but the input field was not rendered. It seemed that "filter" was not turned on. Does anyone know what problem it was related to? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, please accept the answer if it helped you in solving your problem.